# Saving to the Desktop folder on Windows

Tags: python, windows, filepath

I have a problem with saving a file to the "Desktop" folder on Windows. I have two `try` statements. The first tries to save the file for a Mac. The second tries to save it for Windows. The second `except` handler defaults to saving the file in the same folder as the application.

```
try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/' + 
            dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx'))
except:
    try:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.getenv('%HOMEPATH%') + '\\Desktop\\' + 
            dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx')
    except:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(
            self.manager.get_screen('offline').ids.label3.text)
```

When I get an error, it usually says that it was looking for `Users\BobSmith`, but the Windows account should actually have a space in the username. `getpass.getuser()` also returns "BobSmith", but I need to type "Bob Smith" to change to the directory and get to the "Desktop" folder.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')`? To expand an initial '~', it tries `os.environ['HOME']`, `os.environ['USERPROFILE']`, and `join(os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'], os.environ['HOMEPATH'])`. Generally `HOME` isn't defined on Windows, but `USERPROFILE` should be.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it is printing correctly, but when I run the program it still says it couldn't find the path and prints out the path without a space for the user's account i.e. "Couldn't find ...\BobSmith\" when it's needed. I'll try some things tonight to see where exactly this problem is occurring, but my guess it is the open statement. I think I also remember seeing something about the file not being a zip file for openpyxl. I'll post more later tonight when I get back.

Comment: By "correctly" do you mean that it prints `C:\Users\Bob Smith\Desktop`? Also print `os.environ['HOME']`, `os.environ['USERPROFILE']`, and `os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'], os.environ['HOMEPATH'])`.

Comment: I just wrote a quick program that performed the same task of the program using `os.path.normcase(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/OSX/' + dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx'))` . This worked and now I won't need to write two alternative paths for the two systems. It also worked when added to the final program. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.getenv()` will return `None` if the variable is not found. In my opinion it would be more elegant to check if `getenv` does not return `None` and only then execute the the `try`/`except` block.

The more relevant issue seems to be how you try to retrieve `%HOMEPATH%`, although Windows uses `%sys_var%` for system variables, `getenv()` needs them without the `%` sign. In addition `HOMEPATH` returns the path but without the drive, [`HOME` or `USERPROFILE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx) would return the full path.

Try the following modified code and it should work for Windows as well.

```
try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/' + dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx'))
except:
    homepath = os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
    if homepath:
        try:
            wb = opennpyxl.load_workbook(homepath + '\\Desktop\\' + dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx')
        except:
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.manager.get_screen('offline').ids.label3.text)
```

In addition, you could use [sys.platform()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.platform) to execute code specific for your OS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Oh, I didn't know that about the $. After trying this and using os.path.expanduser(), the problem still seems to be persisting where it tries to find User\BobSmith instead of User\Bob Smith. I don't exactly like that Windows does this automatically because I feel like my problem could be temporarily fixed by just taking the space our of the user name. I guess I could just make a local account that isn't linked to a MS account, but that would only be a very temporary patch since other users wouldn't necessarily want to do this. I'll get back with more details later.

Comment: Just created a user account `Test User` (with space) and os.getenv returns a correct path, e.g. `for dir in os.walk(os.getenv('USERPROFILE') + '\\Desktop'):
     print(dir)
('C:\\Users\\Test User\\Desktop', [], ['desktop.ini', 'anotherfile''])`

Comment: I think there was also a small bug somewhere else in the code. I just wrote a quick program that performed the same task of the program using `os.path.normcase(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/OSX/' + dateCur + '_' + timeCur + '_bap_attendance.xlsx'))` . This worked and now I won't need to write two alternative paths for the two systems. It also worked when added to the final program. Thanks for the help!